# Sort column from within the rows on date mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with activated_at and is_paying column where i store the datetime like 2015-03-17 16:06:12, is_paying column is a boolean column with 1 or 0 by default it will be 0, now i want to sort the items by is_paying and within the activated_date range. for example i have records in my table like

```
item_id     is_paying   activated_at

14186       1           2015-03-17 23:40:45 
13647       1           2015-03-17 12:43:52     
4404        0           2015-03-16 11:58:15     
14313       1           2015-03-16 10:42:24     
3806        0           2015-03-15 12:37:36     
10716       1           2015-03-15 11:01:32
```

now i want the output like

```
14186       1           2015-03-17 23:40:45 
13647       1           2015-03-17 12:43:52     
14313       1           2015-03-16 10:42:24     
4404        0           2015-03-16 11:58:15
10716       1           2015-03-15 11:01:32     
3806        0           2015-03-15 12:37:36
```

it should give priority to activated_at date first then within that it should sort is_paying to top if its set to 1, can anyone please help me

so far i have this

```
select items.id, CASE WHEN (DATE(items.activated_at) = DATE(now())) THEN items.is_paying END as sort_order from group by items.id order by sort_order desc, items.activated_at desc
```

Comment: Use multiple columns in `ORDER BY` clause in mysql query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the given expected result looks like you want to sort data first by the date and then then `is_playing` descending order. You can do as

```
select * from table_name order by date(activated_at) desc,is_playing desc;
```

Here is the test case

```
mysql> create table test (item_id int,is_playing int , activated_at datetime);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.09 sec)

mysql> insert into test values (14186,1,'2015-03-17 23:40:45'),(13647,1,'2015-03-17 12:43:52'),(4404,0,'2015-03-16 11:58:15'),(14313,1,'2015-03-16 10:42:24'),(3806,0,'2015-03-15 12:37:36'),(10716,1,'2015-03-15 11:01:32');

mysql> select * from test order by date(activated_at) desc,is_playing desc;
+---------+------------+---------------------+
| item_id | is_playing | activated_at        |
+---------+------------+---------------------+
|   14186 |          1 | 2015-03-17 23:40:45 |
|   13647 |          1 | 2015-03-17 12:43:52 |
|   14313 |          1 | 2015-03-16 10:42:24 |
|    4404 |          0 | 2015-03-16 11:58:15 |
|   10716 |          1 | 2015-03-15 11:01:32 |
|    3806 |          0 | 2015-03-15 12:37:36 |
+---------+------------+---------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY activated_at DESC, is_paying DESC

Comment: doesn't he want desc on activated at?

Comment: same as teh above comment, it ignores is_paying

Answer (score 0):

Do a select `query` with order by:

```
select * from mytable order by date(activated_at) desc, is_paying desc
```

Comment: what output do you get?

Comment: actually this is my sql statement select items.activated_at, dealers.is_paying from items inner join dealers on dealers.id=items.dealer_id order by items.activated_at desc, dealers.is_paying desc

Comment: given your data, the sort on is_paying will have no effect beacuse all dates are different. That is it will sort by date first (that is what you seem to want) and next by is_paying but for each date there is only 1 record and nor further sorting is done

Comment: and i get 2015-03-17 23:40:45  1
2015-03-17 16:06:12  0
2015-03-17 12:43:52  1
2015-03-16 16:00:33  1
2015-02-02 13:54:09  0
2015-02-02 11:58:31  0
2015-02-01 10:42:24  0
2015-01-31 14:47:34  0
2015-01-29 17:39:34  1

Comment: all dates are not different as u can see i have 2 same dates with one is_paying set to 0 and another set to 1

Comment: i just trim out the time by doing DATE(items.activated_at)

Comment: you need to trim off the time in the order by